# How can I delete an item from an online database via android application?

Tags: android

I started to develop Android recently and I'm having difficulty in solving a thing probably much simpler than what I think.

I am creating a CRUD application that communicates with an online database, I can read and enter data, unfortunately I can't delete and modify the list once it is created.

To manage the data that use JSON and the row in the list that I add is made up of three fields: animal_id, animal_name, animal_type.

The activity data on which I read and on which I want to implement methods to modify and delete via listener is formed by the following code:

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ListAnimalActivity extends ListActivity  {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>> animalList;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray animals = null;
    Button button_add;

    private static String url_read = "http://example.com/list_animals.php";
    private static String url_delete = "http://example.com/delete_animal.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        load_ListAnimalActivity();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        load_ListAnimalActivity();
    }

    private void load_ListAnimalActivity(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_animal);
        animalList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,?>>();
        new Read_Object().execute();

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                 ListAnimalActivity.this, animalList,
                 R.layout.row_list, new String[] { "animal_id",
                 "animal_name","animal_type"},
                 new int[] { R.id.animal_id, R.id.animal_name,R.id.animal_type });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListAnimalActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Attenzione!");
                adb.setMessage("Vuoi eliminare l\'elemento \"" + animalList.get(position)+ "\" ?");
                final int posizione = position;
                adb.setNegativeButton("Annulla",new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
                });
                adb.setPositiveButton("Elimina", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        new Delete_Object().execute();
                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }
        });

        button_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ListAnimalActivity.this,CRUDAnimalActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    class Read_Object extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressMessage = new ProgressDialog(ListAnimalActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressMessage.setMessage("Loading ...");
            progressMessage.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressMessage.setCancelable(false);
            progressMessage.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List params = new ArrayList();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read, "POST", params);

            try{
                Log.d("Animals: ", json.toString());
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    animals = json.getJSONArray("animals");
                    for (int i = 0; i < animals.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = animals.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("animal_id");
                        String name = c.getString("animal_name");
                        String type = c.getString("animal_type");
                        HashMap map = new HashMap();
                        map.put("animal_id", id);
                        map.put("animal_name", name);
                        map.put("animal_type", type);
                        animalList.add(map);
                    }
                }       
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            progressMessage.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListAnimalActivity.this, animalList,
                        R.layout.row_list, new String[] { "animal_id",
                        "animal_name","animal_type"},
                        new int[] { R.id.animal_id, R.id.animal_name,R.id.animal_type });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    class Delete_Object extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        private ProgressDialog progressMessage = new ProgressDialog(ListAnimalActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressMessage.setMessage("Deleting ...");
            progressMessage.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressMessage.setCancelable(false);
            progressMessage.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            /*
              Code to delete
            */
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){

        }
    }
}
```

When i click on a list Item, the listener show me the object in this format:
    {animal_type=firstType, animal_name=firstName, animal_id=1}

So my question is: 
How can I collect only animal_id from the array animalList > ?

Comment: are we talking about an SQL like database?

Comment: Yes an MySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animalList is an array list with HashMaps as its elements, so when you call `animalList.get(position)`, it will return a HashMap. To retrieve an animal_id just use :

```
(animalList.get(position)).get(animal_id).toString();
```

Comment: I have another question...when I start my application, my list duplicate itself! How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a Modelclass/Pojo Class (Private variable and getters and setters) for Animals,

```
ArrayList<AnimalModel> animalsArrayList = new ArrayList<AnimalModel>();
```

add the Animals object/data to animalsArrayList and `listview.setAdapter(animalsArrayList);`

then

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Object object = speakerListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            AnimalModel animals_data = (AnimalModel)  object;

             id = animals_data.getAnimal_id()

    // call delete Async with thid Id

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks pretty messy. If I were you I would create a Custom Adapter that extends the base adapter and takes as a parameter either a hashmap or a list that you pass in the constructor. There you can have different listeners. Also if you want to notify the activity you can have the "luxury" to pass an interface as a parameter and notify the activity when something changes. 
 
Regarding the json part, I would create two new classes, one which is a Thread Manager that receives tasks and handles them further and another class where u make the http calls and the json parsing. 
I have done a similar application that receives data from a nebula interface and displays them to the user.